# IBM MobileFirst 7.1 - Windows Phone Hybird App and invoking Java Adapter from native code

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

We are using **MobileFirst 7.1** and deploying a Hybrid Application for **Windows Phone**.

In our **Hybrid** Windows Phone application (which is **Silverlight** application) we want to invoke a MobileFirst Java Adapter.

As we see in the link http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_adapters_endpoint.html we need to use **WLResourceRequest** for Java Adapters, but we try to use it in our Silverlight App, we cannot find WLResourceRequest. Does this class exist only for Universal Windows Phone Apps?

In our case we need to invoke a Java adapter from our Silverlight Application. It’s not very clear how to do that.

When we check another page in the documentation: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/server-side-development/invoking-adapter-procedures-native-windows-phone-8-applications/, we read see in the introduction about WLResourceRequest, but later in the same page it's not used, and we have only Javascript adapter invocation sample code, not Java Adapter.

My question is: How to invoke Mobile First Java from my MF Hybrid (Silverlight) App (from native code) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement in the tutorial regarding `WLResourceRequest` in Silverlight apps is an error. Silverlight apps only support `WL.Client.invokeProcedure`. The tutorial will be corrected.

As such, Java adapters are not supported in Silverlight apps.
What you could do is invoke a JavaScript adapter that uses Java code: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/server-side-development/javascript-adapters/using-java-adapters/

Comment: What about WLResourceRequest when called from Javascript code (in hybrid application HTML/JS code) ? Does it work fine on Windows Phone 8 ?

Comment: Doesn't matter, not supported in Windows Phone.

Comment: @IdanAdar Can we give the native implementation of WLResourceRequest in windows phone? And does windows supports this?